# PyQt4 TableWidget.itemChanged causes function to fire multiple times

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pyqt4

I have a MySql database that I am viewing with tableWidget. I am trying to update the database when the item inside the cell changes. It's working, however, when the database refreshes the update function gets called for every cell that is refreshed because as cells are getting created they all change.

I am using:

```
self.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.update)
```

Is there something else I should be using so that the function fires only when the USER changes the item.?

Comment: One: kindly check the value inside cell is same or not, then update the database, second: kindly provide more code to understand better.

Comment: Are you using [QSqlTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html)? And if not, why not?